# Parallelize matplotlib.animation when running .to_html5_video()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-animation, data-representation

I was wondering whether there is a straight-forward way to parallelize the method `animation.FuncAnimation.to_html5_video()` which takes a lot of time. While running it only uses 1 of my cpu's cores at a given time and I am guessing the process should be parallelizable. Any ideas to make this work without digging too much?

I need this to plot some time-evolving curves from an ODE system but it takes a lot of time

PS When I say parallelize, I mean e.g. using a library like `multiprocessing`